# Delete the rows that have a single zero in Pandas

Tags: python, excel

I have imported an excel sheet using Pandas like this:

```py
w = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\lvk\Downloads\Softwares\Prob.xls", header=None)
```

Once I imported the excel sheet, I need to delete the rows with even a single zero in any column.
Are there any functions in Python to do that?
Please let me know.

Input:

```
row1:  0  4  3   5
row2:  1  6  5   61
row3:  1  3  6   0
```

Expected output:

```
1  6  5  61
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has very powerful interfaces for [indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).  Among them are the use of the `loc` keyword to access by rows, and square brackets to pass indexing logic to `loc`.  Normally you might use the names of your columns to do logical operations on their values.  Here I don't know the index or columns of your excel data, so we will just loop through all the columns that are there.

```
# We are going to look in each column
for col in w.columns:
    # And select only the rows in w that don't have a 0 in that column
    w = w.loc[w[column] != 0]
```